# Why am I getting a reference error and syntax error on my site?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set up some boilerplate code and I'm getting two errors.  The first is an unexpected token syntax error on the `utils.js` file and a reference error on the `scripts.js` file.  Can anyone explain why these errors are returning when everything is in the right place and being referenced?

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="utils.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="main" width="450" height="400"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

**utils.js**

```
var Utils = {
    utils.captureMouse = function(element){
        var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0};

        element.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
            var x, y;
            if(event.pageX || event.pageY){
                x = event.pageX;
                y = event.pageY;
            }
            else{
                x = event.ClientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
                y = event.ClientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            }
            x -= element.offsetLeft;
            y -= element.offsetTop;
            mouse.x = x;
            mouse.y = y;
        });
        return mouse;
    }
};
```

**script.js**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("main");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    mouse = Utils.captureMouse(canvas);

    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
        console.log("X: " +mouse.x);
        console.log("Y: " +mouse.y);
    })
})
```

Here are the errors

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token.             utils.js:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: utils is not defined       script.js:4
    (anonymous function) @ script.js:4
```

Comment: show us the actual errors please :)

Comment: @StephenWright will do, is a screenshot okay?

Comment: @Robert: No, a screenshot is not okay. Copy&paste the error messages here, and show us from what lines they come (and possibly their stack traces if they have ones)

Comment: Maybe `utils.captureMouse =` *is* a syntax error in an object literal?

Comment: `utils.js` has invalid syntax. `o = {a.b = c}`, not valid.

Comment: @elclanrs how would I make it valid?

Comment: @Bergi I added the errors to the question

Comment: @Robert: `Utils = {captureMouse: function(){...}}`

Comment: @elclanrs that fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't valid syntax:

```
var Utils = {
  utils.captureMouse = function(){/.../}
};
```

On that second line, `utils` is not defined.  And that should be setting a property, not executing an assignment operation.  Perhaps you meant this?:

```
var Utils = {
  captureMouse: function(){/.../}
};
```

The second error is simply a result of the first, since `Utils` was never effectively defined.  Correcting that should correct both.

Comment: Yep, that worked.  Thank you.  I was following along in a book and that's how their syntax was written

Answer (score 0):

Try to attach the `eventListener` to document.body and not to window and/or append utils.js at the end of the body. I think the problem is that the `<canvas></canvas>` element wasn`t created yet